# Using any loop in C#, count from 0 to 20 with a message for each line and for each number divisible by 5, have a special message

Tags: c#, loops

I am currently working on loops (for, while, and do while). I understand the basics and have successfully been able to do the basics with little to no effort.
I am currently working on a problem that goes just a touch beyond the basics where the end result will show a message ("Pass {0} in the loop") where obviously the "{0}" is the number loop. However, I am trying to create a separate message for those number that are divisible by 5 (5, 10,15,20). Could I get a pointer in the right direction. I played around with the ideas of using an "if" statement or even a "foreach", but have had no luck since yesterday finding a possible viable option or simply did not know how to phrase it properly. Below is my current code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Do while loop positive numbers");

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pass {0} in the loop", i++);

        } while (i <= 20);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. You all gave me a lot of good information to play with and many ways (slight variations) in which to do it.

Comment: You might want to look up the definitions of "modulo" and "remainder".  The difference can be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't write code for you but would like to give hint

You can use an `if condition` inside the `do while loop` to check if it is `divisible by 5` then display the special message. You can use `%` operator to check whether the number is divisible by some other number or not

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Do while loop positive numbers");

        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Pass {0} in the loop", i++);
            //if your number is divisible by 5 then display message 
        } while (i <= 20);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the remainder operator: %

Combined with an `if` statement you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

simply check if it is divisible by 5

```
if(i%5==0)
  Console.WriteLine("{0} is divisible by 5",i);
```

% or modules operator is used to get the remainder of the division

on side note ,stackoverflow is not a good place to start programming,other websites or tutorials are more helpful

Comment: Thank you. I am currenty using a C# book for learning and study. I only use this website or any other for research and professional opinions. Books do not explain everything :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
if (i%5==0)
print your special message
```

Answer (score 0):

**The `for` loop**

```
for( int i = 0; i <= 20; i++ )
{
    if( i % 5 == 0 && i > 0 )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0} is divisible by 5.", i );
    }
}
```

**The do...while equivalent**

```
int x = 0;

do
{
    if( x % 5 == 0 && x > 0 )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0} is divisible by 5.", x );
    }

    x++;
}
while( x <= 20 );
```

Note that I prefer starting loops with zero unless there is a good reason to do otherwise. Indexes are zero-based in .NET and (IMO) it's good to write code that follows that pattern.

As everyone is pointing out, the important thing here is the modulus operator (`%`).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

And for a complete breakdown of why the .NET modulus operator is really a remainder operator:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx

Comment: Just wondering why you bother doing a `string.Format` inside a WriteLine, won't it internally call Format anyway?

Comment: @Blam - habit...I've gotten into the pattern of cleaning up messy concatenation with string.Format() due to the spotty implementation of formattable expressions in the BCL. But it is superfluous in this case; I'll remove it.

Comment: Thank you for that link (now bookmarked) and my book said the same thing about starting with "0".

Answer (score 0):

Just use the operator % and check for the remainder of the division i % 5. If it is 0 then i is divisble by 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the the `%` operator in your `if` statement.

```
if((i%5) == 0)
   divisible by 5 message
else
   the regular message
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a number is divisible by another number you can use the `%` or *modulo* operator, you can use it the same way as an addition or division operator, `a = c % b`.
**The modulo operator gives you the remainder of a division**. So if you did `51 % 5`, you would get *1* as 5 goes into 51 ten times with *one* left over. Therefore if when you use the modulo operator and the result is 0, the first number is divisible by the second with no remainder.

Therefore, what you need to do is set up an **if statement** to check if the modulo of i is 5, or whatever you need. There are lots of tutorials on if statements out there, so I wont really go into detail about the code.

The following will check if I is divisible by 5, and then write to the Console if it is. Add this to your loop:

```
if(i % 5 == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is divisible by 5!", i);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;

namespace loop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i= 1;//start
            while (i<=20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                i++;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

//Just another way to look at the problem in a more simplified way

Comment: It's better to add some details, e.g. explaining why your answer differs from the others (if so, actually), rather than posting just code.

Comment: @FrancescoB. Thank you  for your info